# Is it okay to set field mapping limit in elastic to 50k?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

My application is a survey creation app where user can create survey with many questions of different types. Each survey can then be shared to any number of people whose responses are recorded as below...
1 response looks something like this:

```
{
          "id" : 256,                                        // submission id
          "timeTaken" : "39.00",
          "startTime" : "2020-07-19T05:37:38.873Z",
          "state" : "COMPLETED",
          "completedTime" : "2020-07-19T05:38:17.873Z",
          "deviceType" : "COMPUTER",
          "ip" : null,
          "account_id" : 2,
          "channel_id" : 48,
          "contact_id" : null,
          "survey_id" : 10,
          "trigger_id" : 93,
          "trigger_contact_id" : null,
          "locked" : false,
          "location" : null,
          "language" : null,
          "submission_id" : 256,
          "question_90" : {
            "skipped" : false,
            "answer_choices" : [ 79 ]
          },
          "question_122" : {
            "skipped" : false,
            "otherChoice" : null,
            "answer_choices" : [ 115, 113, 111, 110, 114 ]
          },
          "question_106" : {
            "skipped" : false,
            "answer_choices" : [ 85 ]
          },
          "question_120" : {
            "answer_txt": "Great service",
            "skipped" : false
          },
          "question_118" : {
            "answer_txt": "Hello people",
            "skipped" : false
          },
          "question_121" : {
            "skipped" : false,
            "answer_date" : "2020-06-04T20:01:49.783Z",
            "answer_timezone" : 330
          },
          "question_108" : {
            "skipped" : false,
            "answer_int" : "93"
          },
          "question_105" : {
            "skipped" : false,
            "answer_string" : "+1 202 9932219"
          },
          "question_93" : {
            "skipped" : false,
            "answer_string" : "Kyra60@yahoo.com"
          },
          "question_117" : {
            "skipped" : false
          },
          "question_92" : {
            "skipped" : false,
            "answer_txt" : "composite"
          },
          "question_107" : {
            "skipped" : false,
            "answer_bool" : true
          },
      }
```

I need all the field here for analysis and querying.
But most of the time the doc field limit exceeds the elasticsearch default limit of 1000.
I am pretty sure that its 1000 for performance, but how can I honor this and insert a document which may have like 20k + fields.

Any insight on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely not go in a mapping explosion direction.
keys are stored in memory so you'll have an over consumption of RAM and poor performances. You have it documented here : elastic.co/blog/found-crash-elasticsearch#mapping-explosion

You could easily map your answers with a very few quantity of keys by using a nested datatype.

```
"answers": [
          {
           "question_id": 122,
            "skipped" : false,
            "otherChoice" : null,
            "answer_choices" : [ 115, 113, 111, 110, 114 ]
          }
]
```

Comment: again, but huge entries in nested will put a lot of performance penalty.. I guess, he needs to think of a better design

Comment: any design recommendations or better insights on how i should move forward 

Comment: @Jaycreation very nice document

Comment: @ElasticsearchNinja Any design recommendations or any points that can help me to tackle this?

Comment: 1) 50K fields is definitely still too many, but that blog post is from 2014 and quite a few things have changed since then (sparsity is not causing so much disk overhead any more, more off-heap datastructures). 2) Depending on how you want to use those fields, the new [flattened](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/flattened.html) field type might be a good solution.